# Appropriate method in python to hash some data into a virtually collision-proof key

Tags: python, md5, uuid, sha1, hashlib

What is an appropriate method in python to hash some data into a virtually collision proof key (so probably 128 bits or so)? System still uses Python 2.7.

I was looking into hashlib's Sha1 and MD5, but its hard to find information on these hashes that are not in the context of security.

I simply need something that:

- Will produce that same key for the same data
- Unlikely to have key collisions (so probably about 128 bits or so)
- Is not slow (hashes meant for security tend to be intentionally slow)

Comment: Are you asking for a recommendation of a library?

Comment: Python has a built in data type called dict, which is equivalent to hashmap (is is basically a hashmap). Uses json like format and the keys are hashed giving O(1) access

Comment: @quamrana - Yes, I'm using hashlib.sha1 right now

Comment: @dumbPy - I need a key that is virtually impossible to have collisions. In practice, this means about 128 bits from an algorithm that doesn't tend to produce unnecessary collisions. I don't know the inner workings of dict, but it probably uses a much more lightweight hashing algorithm that does produce collisions now and then. When this happens, it probably stores both values in a collection associated with the collided hash. Thats all assuming there is a way to get the hash key out of a dict.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing.

I like to base64 encode stuff like this cause it avoids problems by reducing the character set to one thats accepted/compatible in most places without ballooning out the size of the key too much like hex encoding would. You never know know where you're going to want to stick this ID/key in the future.

I removed the '=' sign at the end because sometimes it causes problems with URLs. Mathematically, this makes the id more likely to have a collision because the '=' is indicating information. But I think the left over data is more than sufficient to prevent collisions, especially since a sha1 is 160 bits instead of 128. UUIDs are 128 bytes because although technically possible to have a UUID collision, the odds of it actually happening are so infinitesimally small that a collision is virtually impossible (this is assuming you use a good hashing algorithm that has a nice, random distribution).

```
import hashlib
import base64 

def get_key(raw_text):

    m = hashlib.sha1()
    m.update(raw_text)
    raw_bytes_key = m.digest()
    key           = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(raw_bytes_key).replace('=', '')

    return key
```